# Problem inserting data into a nodejs and mongodb backend with reactjs frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have an API running on nodejs with mongodb, and I am trying to insert data from the reactjs frontend.
This data comes from the user's Token and the id of a book that the user is interested in

Model:

```
let BookInterested = new Schema({
  book: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Book",
    required: true
  },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
  completed: { type: Boolean, default: false }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("BookInterested", BookInterested);
```

The user and the book are coming from other models with are Book and User.

I have a Route with a simple post method:

Route:

```
router.post(
  "/book/:bookId/interesteds",
  auth.authenticate(),
  (req, res) => {
    meService.createInterested(req, res);
  }
);
```

The Service has all the logic behind the route.

meService:

```
createInterested: function(req, res) {
    let interested = {
      user: req.user.id, //User Id from token
      book: req.params.bookId, //book Id from route

    };

    let record = new BookInterested(interested);

    record.save(err => {
      if (err) return helper.error(res, "Error while creating " + err);

      if (!record) return helper.error(res, "Record not found");



      return res.json({ success: true });
    });
  },
```

In my frontend with is in reactjs I have  the functions to fetch the books and the users

```
 componentWillMount() {
    this.retrieveBooks(this.props.params.id);
    this.retrieveUser();
  }
```

with is working just fine, my problem now is that I need a button where, when clicked, the user demonstrates that he or she has an interest in the book, like so:

```
          <Button

              onClick={() => this.setState({ open: !open, disabled: true })}
              className="btn btn-big btn-tenho-interesse"
              aria-expanded={open}
              disabled={this.state.disabled}
            >
              Im Interested
            </Button>
```

I create the handleclick function, but it is not working

handleclick:

```
handleClick = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    Request.post(
      `/me/books/${this.props.params.id}/interesteds`,
      req,
      res,
      res => {
        if (res.success) {
          Alert.success(
            "success"
          );
        } else
          Alert.error(
            "error"
          );
      }
    );
  };
```

I'm getting all sorts of errors, like "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" and "res.json is not a function" and many others.

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the backend receive and process the request properly? If so, what is `req` in your final code block? Where do you get your `TypeError` error? In the front or backend?

Comment: @JayGould i believe the back receive the request, i have it in my route  `(req, res)`,
and the `TypeError ` is comming from the frontend.

Comment: Move your ```return res.json({ success: true });``` out of the ```record.save()``` this may solve your "res.json is not a function"